# Not able to call the function in terminal

Tags: git, terminal, atom-editor

At first when I tried `git commit` it opened "Atom" (showing "Aborting commit due to empty commit message" in terminal) after adding commit message and closing Atom this same issue in bold was shown so I tried using `git commit -m "commit message"`, it worked.

Now again when I tried `git tag`, it opened atom again and this time yet again when I closed atom it showing this same issue

I have already tried git config.

```
$ Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released.
Function provided here: Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LaLaLa\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.42.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\github\lib\worker.js:79:22
Remote event names: destroyed, crashed
```

Comment: it looks like your atom is not properly releasing resources. try some other editor for editing commits

Comment: Not actually a Git bug; I added the [tag:atom-editor] tag.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a access problem for Atom, see [this post](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/769) for more info.

Tldr, if you have access to linux commands run `sudo chown -R USERNAME /home/USERNAME/.atom` to set the correct rights.